# Incorrect nodeName from activeElement in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, forms

When a text input has focus and the enter key is pressed, `document.activeElement.nodeName` should return `INPUT`. This works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but in Internet Explorer/Edge it returns `BUTTON`.

I'm working on a custom form with heavy JavaScript and Internet Explorer reports the incorrect nodeName, which is causing a big problem.

[See this fiddle for the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/p1yzLumn/4/)

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Try to use `tagName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the method to output `outerHTML`, you can see that the text input has focus in Chrome, but the submit input has focus in IE.

Binding the event to `keydown` instead of `keyup` or changing the second `input` from `submit` to `button` seems to work.  Pressing `enter` in a form is supposed to activate the first `submit` input, and I guess one of the things IE does when it handles this is to give focus to the `submit` input.

`keydown` probably works because that event is raised before IE activates the `submit` button.